# Class to update Account's active__c not working

Tags: soql, query, opportunity, account, dml

I made a class in a trailhead playground to query some opps, then the accounts, and some fields related to them. My objective was to access the Account's Active__c field and change the value from 'yes' to 'no'.

I made the class and called it from the anonymous console. When I insert some System.debugs, they show me I got the right value for every account. But when the class executions finish, and I redo the same query, the field remains unchanged.

The code is:

```
public Opportunity[] flagActive(){
        Opportunity[] opps = [Select name, Id, StageName, Account.Name, Account.Active__c, AccountId from Opportunity where StageName = 'Closed Won'];
        for(Opportunity opp : opps){
            opp.Account.Active__c = 'No';
            opp.Account.Name     = opp.Name;
        }
        update opps;
        return opps;
    }
```

and the piece of code I made in anonymous console is:

```
class nc = new class();
nc.flagActive();
```

Why did the values remain unaltered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing DML only affects the object the DML is performed on. It has no effect on related records (except for causing rollup summary fields to re-evaluate on parent records, and whatever you are doing in any Opportunity trigger, Process Builder, etc...).

If you want to update the accounts, you need to perform DML directly on those Accounts.

Related records are themselves proper SObjects. Since you queried for account fields, `Opportunity.Account` is an honest to goodness `Account`. Add the embedded Account record to a list, and then perform DML on the list of Accounts.